# Scanner class , hasNextLine give true even there is not any next line

Tags: java

My input txt file has this content:

> aa1 aa2  
>       bb1 bb2 
>       cc1 cc2

After cursor is going to the last line, how does hasNextLine() method give true while reading cc1 and cc2? I thought I would only get aa1 to bb2.

Output:

> aa1 
>           aa2 
>           bb1
>           bb2
>           cc1
>           cc2

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File f = new File("K:\\Test\\a.txt");
        System.out.println(f.exists());
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(f);
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(reader.next());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think when `hasNextLine` would return false? on the last line, the middle of the file, or when no data is aviable that can be read?

Comment: Why do you think the last line should not be returned?

Comment: Ideally it should be : while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println(reader.nextLine());

        }

Answer (score 0):

Either use hasNextLine() with nextLine(), or use hasNext(), with next(). Mixing those can result in undesired behavior (unless used deliberately). See their documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Quoting the next() method:

> Returns the next token if it matches the specified pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext(Pattern) returned true. If the match is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched the pattern.

And also, in the Scanner class documentation, you can find this:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

So, the scanner reads the first line, it advances to the first delimiter (the white space) and prints the first part (aa1). Then, still on the same line, it prints the second part (aa2). Then, it moves to the second line, prints (bb1), then it prints (bb2), and still the while condition is true, since there is also a next line. So, finally, at the third line, it prints the first part (cc1), it prints the second part (cc2) and then stops, since there is no other line.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I understood what's the problem. and really thanks for edit my problem in correct manner . Next time i will keep remember that :D